# Reaction of phosphonates with conjugated carbonyl compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, organophosphorus-compounds

I was wondering whether the phosphonate ion would do a Michael addition on to the double bond rather than attacking the $\ce{C=O}$ bond to form the alkene product as it usually does (e.g. in a Horner–Wadsworth–Emmons reaction).

Comment: Something to do with HSAB?